# Is there a way to repeat quotation marks at the beginning of each line of text in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, typography

I am looking for a way to show a quotation mark at the beginning of each line of a quotation. Is there a way to do this in HTML/CSS?

In older, pre-20th century typography, quotation marks were often placed not only at the beginning and the end of a quotation, but also at the beginning of every line of the quoted text (see example below). I would like to mimic this on an HTML-website, but in such a way that the quotation marks stay to the left even if the lines get rearranged, e.g. a smaller screen. Is there a way to do this?

Below is an example of the result I want to achieve:

[image]

(example of multiple quotation marks to the left side of a longer quotation in *Het leven van den H. Augustinus*)

Comment: I think you may need javascript to deduce this

Answer (score 3):

**CSS Only Solution**

It surprised me, but you actually can add this old quote effect using only css.

This solution prepends a pseudo element to the block quote using [:before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before). This element is filled with quote symbols and [overflow-wrap: anywhere](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) is used to stack the symbols vertically. Then we align them to the left of the text to create the effect.

The solution seems to automatically handle container and font size changes without problem.  Yet, it could be improved more. For example, by removing the extra whitespace between the quote and the character.

**Snippet**

Run the snippet to view.

```css
h4 {
  color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}


.old-quote {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left:0.8rem;
}

.old-quote:before {
  content: '""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0.8rem;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
}

.old-quote:after {
  content: '"';
  width: 0.8rem;
}

/* fr - les guillemets */

.old-quote-fr:before {
   content: '««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««««';
}
.old-quote-fr:after {
  content: "»";
}
```

```html
<h4>Test I - short quote</h4>
<div class="old-quote">
Alles hat ein Ende, nur die Wurst hat zwei
</div>

<h4>Test II - long quote</h4>
<div class="old-quote old-quote-fr"> 
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas c?
</div>

<h4>Test III - large font quote</h4>
<div class="old-quote" style="width:50%;font-size:1.5em;"> 
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo?
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, this seems to work indeed, thank you! I don't consider the whitespace to be a problem. Unfortunately though, it seems I have to display the quotes in a seperate block. When I have a quotation that begins within a paragraph (by adding text before and after the quote, changing "display: inline-block;" to "display: inline;", and by changing the <div class="old-quote">  to <span class="old-quote">), the quotation marks appear not to the left of the tex, but behind the text of the next quoted lines below the starting point of the quotation. Might there be a workaround for this?

Comment: @KarelVissers - Yes, it can also be done inline, but you would need to add the first and last quote marks to the text.  See this [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zug2rtwo/)

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend the solution by @yogi, but would change a little thing. You can use HTML-Entity-Codes to display the special Character:

```
&laquo; //displays «
```

Just set the content to the Character-Code:

```
content: '&laquo;';
```

Comment: Good advice as quote symbols can vary by culture, e.g. , les guillemets. +1

Answer (score 1):

Another pure CSS solution, which works with starting and ending in the middle of lines like your sample text is to make use of `box-decoration-break: clone` and an SVG background image.

`box-decoration-break: clone` both repeats any padding on elements at the start and end of each line, and also repeats the background image on each line. By using padding-left on the `<q>` elements, and a non-repeating background image of a `«` character, we can get the desired effect.

For Chromium and Safari, box-decoration-break needs a -webkit- prefix.

```css
q {
  quotes:none;
  padding-left: 9px;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 1 7 24" width="7" height="24"><text x="0" y="16">«</text></svg>');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
q:after {
  content:'';
  padding-left: 9px;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 1 7 24" width="7" height="24"><text x="0" y="16">»</text></svg>');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <q>Pellentesque fermentum ornare venenatis. Cras vitae nisl sit amet eros ultricies accumsan tincidunt vel ex. Vivamus id mollis lectus. In ullamcorper mi id nisl faucibus, non condimentum enim egestas. Donec sodales, tellus quis eleifend tristique, sem augue feugiat lectus, a vestibulum odio sem sit amet risus.</q> Etiam faucibus augue dolor, <q>eget viverra nisi</q> luctus eget. Vivamus sed rhoncus leo. Maecenas vestibulum dui ut velit dignissim, eu auctor turpis sagittis. Donec placerat mollis aliquet.

<p>Nullam efficitur ante id volutpat dictum. Aliquam pretium rutrum sapien, a blandit neque venenatis nec. Proin nec finibus ex. Donec vitae rutrum nisl. Duis molestie feugiat ornare. Donec porttitor, ante ullamcorper scelerisque tincidunt, odio <q>tellus rutrum sem, vel placerat ex magna eget sem. Quisque venenatis diam nec purus posuere efficitur. Integer ac facilisis nulla, sit amet aliquam ipsum. Sed tellus arcu, maximus sed urna ac, pretium condimentum nibh. Vivamus dapibus vestibulum pretium. Praesent in sem auctor, eleifend libero at, tristique tortor. Vivamus varius finibus nisi. Fusce elementum ante nibh, a pretium enim laoreet nec. Vivamus metus eros, ullamcorper vel leo non, volutpat consequat erat.</q>
```